# UICollectionView delegate methods not being called properly

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView`, and in each cell I set the text of a `UILabel`, in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, from an array:

```
let array = ["New York City", "Chicago", "San Francisco"]
```

The cells appear labeled correctly onscreen, but when I try to log the value of the label in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, it logs the value as `nil`. And if I try to do anything else in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` (like change the cell's opacity), no changes are executed.

What could be going wrong here?

---

Relevant code:

The view controller has superclasses `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

The collection view cell's class declaration:

```
class PickerCell: UICollectionViewCell {
var label = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    label.frame = contentView.bounds
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    label.font = font.body
    contentView.addSubview(label)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

Creating the collection view:

```
func createPickerView() {
    let pickerFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = PickerLocationFlowLayout()
    pickerFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: 40)
    pickerFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    let pickerView: UICollectionView
    pickerView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height), collectionViewLayout: pickerFlowLayout)
    pickerView.registerClass(PickerCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PickerCellId")
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(pickerView)
}
```

Selecting a cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PickerCellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PickerCell
    print("indexpath: \(indexPath.row), label: \(cell.label.text)")
    // Prints the correct row number, but nil for the label.
}
```

Comment: Have you added collectionView.delegate and .dataSource = self?

Comment: Yes, as shown in `createPickerView()`, the delegate and dataSource are indeed set to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'd made a stupid mistake. In `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, I was calling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`, which I should have called `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.